# Spring Hibernate Many-to-Many Association with transient value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have two tables Teacher and Student

```
Teacher(Teacher_id, Teacher_name)
Student(student_id, student_name)
Teacher_Student(id, Teacher_id, Student_id)
```

I have corresponding model also for each table such as Teacher.java Student.java and TeacherStudent.java

I want to be able to get a result set with list of teachers information and no_of_students per teacher. Eg:

```
Teacher_id, Teacher_name, No_of_students
```

I do not want to get a list if teachers and then loop through each teacher_id and find the number of students.

I have a SQL query that does this in one query, but how do I make this work on hibernate. Also I want the No_of_Students value to be transient.

Comment: what did you mean by `but how do I make this work on hibernate`

Comment: I mean to say without having to do two queries, i.e. first query for fetching the list of teachers and then going through each teacher_id to get no_of_students. I am using NamedQuery in the models. So which model should this query reside in?

Answer (score 1):

No need for two queries you can just use :

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT t.id, t.name, t.listStudent.size() FROM Teacher");
```

This will return a List of an array of Object like this :

```
List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
```

To get the information you can use :

```
List<Teacher> listTeachers = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object[] info : result){
    listTeachers.add(
       new Teacher(
          (Long) info[0],   // the id
          (String) info[1], // the name
          (Long) info[2]    // the number of students
       )
   );
}
```

I assume in your Teacher Entity you have a constructor :

```
public Teacher(String id, String name, Long nbrStudent){
   this.id = id;
   this.name = name;
   this.nbrStudent = this.listStudent.size();
}
```

and a `@Transient` variable :

```
@Transient
private @Getter @Setter Long nbrStudent;
```

---

Or in one step :

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT com.namepackage.Teacher(t.id, t.name, t.listStudent.size()) FROM Teacher"
);
List<Teacher> result = query.getResultList();
```

Note that I used `com.namepackage.Teacher(t.id, t.name, t.listStudent.size())`